# Exception while deploying lambda function using ASK CLI

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I was trying to Build a fact skill as per instructions  given in https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-fact.

Cloned repository, initialized the ASK CLI and installed npm dependencies.

Then I tried to deploy the skill and the lambda function in one step by running the command ask deploy. But it shows `AccessDeniedException`. Please help me to resolve the issue

> `-------------------- Create Skill Project --------------------`
>
> `Profile for the deployment: [default] Skill Id: amzn1.ask.skill.1234ab-1234`
>
> `Skill deployment finished. Model deployment finished. Create Lambda error. AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::12345678:user/ASK_CLI_USER is not authorized to perform: lambda:CreateFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:12345678:function:what_name_you_want_to_name_the_lambda`

Please Note:

- Installed and set up ASK CLI following instructions in the below link:
  https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html
- Set Up Credentials for an Amazon Web Services (AWS) Account CLI following instructions in the below link:
  https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/set-up-credentials-for-an-amazon-web-services-account.html
- Created a user ASK_CLI_USER and created a new policy with the permissions

  ```json
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "iam:CreateRole",
          "iam:GetRole",
          "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
          "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam:::role/ask-"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "lambda:AddPermission",
          "lambda:CreateFunction",
          "lambda:GetFunction",
          "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
          "lambda:ListFunctions"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:ask-"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",    
        "Action": [
          "logs:FilterLogEvents",
          "logs:getLogEvents",
          "logs:describeLogStreams"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:::log-group:/aws/lambda/ask-"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The resource you should be restricting to is `"arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:ask-*"`. It looks like you're missing the asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

It says pretty clear:

> AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::12345
>   678:user/ASK_CLI_USER is not authorized to perform:
>   lambda:CreateFunction on resource:
>   arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:12345678:function:what_name_you_want_to_name_the_lambda

Go into your console and add proper permissions to user `ASK_CLI_USER`

Comment: "lambda:CreateFunction" permission is already added to ASK_CLI_USER.            { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "lambda:AddPermission", "lambda:CreateFunction", "lambda:GetFunction", "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode", "lambda:ListFunctions" ], "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:ask-" }